# load model.json for tensorflowjs in reactjs not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to load a model.json file with it's weights.bin from the root directory in my react app.

When I call an example I found online from storage.googleapis.com it works but loading from my root doesn't.

The contents of App.js in my react app...

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");

// example model - working
async function predict() {
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/model.json"
  );
  console.log(typeof model);
}

// my model - not working
async function predictAlt() {
  const myModel = await tf.loadLayersModel("file://my-model.json");
  console.log(typeof model);
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={predict} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>
        example model
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={predictAlt} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>
        my model
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file URI scheme `file://url` is only for loading model server side. To load the model in the browser, the user can be prompted to select the model topology(model.json) and weight files. The [doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel) contains an exemple of how to load a model by prompting the user using file input elements.

If the user is not to be requested to select the model files, then the model needs to be served by a server. The model.json and the weights can for instance be in the assets folder of the application deployed. Then the url would just need to be pointing to the `model.json` without `file://` as follows:

```
const myModel = await tf.loadLayersModel("assets/my-model.json");
```

If there are some errors in loading the model, looking at the network tab in the developer console would help to see if the file is found or not

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this. When I try this I get...

Failed to parse model JSON of response from my-model.json. Please make sure the server is serving valid JSON for this request.

I get a status code 200 on the request URL in the network tab. I don't think this confirms it can access the file because when I spell the file wrong eg /my-modelx.json  I still get a 200 status.

Comment: I also made a mistake in the code above. the second function should log the type of myModel not model.

Comment: That's not possible. If the file is not found, you will have a 404. What do you mean by the model's name? `typeof model` will log the name of the class which is `model`

Comment: That's what I expected to see but I think this is a react/codesandbox issue because even when I enter the url to the .json file, it just opens the app. On my server I get some json on screen as I would expect. It logs object

Comment: Yes, I am able to load the model locally. You have to find out with the config of codesandbox. typeof model will always return object. If you want to check if it is an instance of a certain class, you will rather need to use `instanceof`

Comment: Thank you, did you change any of the code? In that case, I will download the project and work on it locally for now. Okay I will make a note of instanceof

Comment: I moved my-model.json and the weight file in the public folder and `const myModel = await tf.loadLayersModel("/my-model.json");`